# DELPHI - How to change a TButton background color in a VCL Form Application?

Tags: delphi, button, colors, vcl, tbutton

In my Delphi VCL Form Application, I have to change the background color of a TButton.
Is there a way to apply this change without using third-party components?

Thanks.

Comment: an example component inherited from TButton with sourcecan be found here http://delphi.about.com/od/vclwriteenhance/l/aa061104a.htm

Comment: @bummi there is no source code at the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change the color of a [`TButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton) component directly, instead you must use a third-party component or owner draw the button ([`BS_OWNERDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: How can I implement the drawing of the Button?

Comment: The link in the answer covers that. You'll need to respond to `WM_DRAWITEM`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a panel.
2. Change panel's color to any color.
3. Empty panel's caption.
4. Create a SpeedButton inside the panel.
5. **Set SpeedButton's Flat property True.**
6. Set SpeedButton's Align propert alClient.
7. Voila! Here is your button with color!

Original source: https://engineertips.wordpress.com/2020/07/21/delphi-button-background-color/

Comment: 10.2 Tokyo. This works only in the design mode. When I try this in source code, the color goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Nice tip, thank you, Xel Naga!

You can also place an image on the panel, to make your button even nicer.
Here I’ve added an image of a Yellow- Glass- button.
To get the rounded corners, you shape the panel like this >>

```
SetWindowRgn(Panel1.Handle, CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, 65, 40), True);
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Next level after that, you can add 3 more images (on top of each-other) for button states: Mouse Over (OnMouseEnter), Button Pressed (OnMouseDown) and Button Disabled. Just change the Visible state of the images to reveal the one you want to see...