# How do I change the color of a button and its caption?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I would like to change the colour of a button, for example make it from grey --> yellow. Do you know if this is possible? I didn't see any colour option in the button's property, but there must be a way to change its colour.

If it is not possible, please tell me if and how i can change the colour of button's caption. I have selected different colours, but it still hasn't changed, it remains black, perhaps i am doing something wrong.

I am using delphi7.

Comment: You do know that this is highly awkward to do if Windows themes are enabled. (It was much easier back in the Win 9x era).

Comment: TButton is a windows common control. You can owner-draw a caption.  But the results of mixing "stuff I drew over top of whatever windows draws" results in some awkward situations.

Comment: @Warren P: True, but IMHO it is very seldom worth it.

Comment: Agreed.   If you want to draw a control, draw the whole control.

Comment: For a `TButton`, you cannot change either button or text color using built in properties. Note also that if you are using XP themes, then the control is drawn by Windows using the theme engine and you've got no chance at all of changing appearance.

If you use `TBitBtn`, then you can change the text color with `Font.Color`. If you paint the control yourself then you'll get control.

Comment: Ok, thanks, But i've never used TbitBtn before, is it the same as Tbutton?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664495/delphi-how-to-change-a-tbutton-background-color-in-a-vcl-form-application

Answer (score -2):

for change font color of button , in project->option->application->Appearance use custom style for project
and then in button styleelements property disable sefont

Comment: This question is about Delphi 7, which did not have styles. Delphi 7 is mentioned in both the title and tags. The post was written in 2013, long before visual styles were introduced. How is this answer relevant?